# FCM with Cloud Datastore

Tags: java, firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Java App Engine standard project (for about 4 years), using the Cloud Datastore (with Objectify). One of my services is using GCM to push notifications to mobile clients. Google has announced that GCM is deprecated and will be shut down 11th of April, and from then on Firebase messaging should be used instead of GCM.

After reading the docs it seemed straight forward to migrate, however I cannot create a Firebase database on my existing project, apparently I need to create a new App Engine project for this?

My question is, how can I use messaging on my existing App Engine project?
Starting a new project seems to me a bit overkill just to migrate from GCM to FCM.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, once you select a database for your GCP project, [you can't switch back](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore#choosing_a_database). That's why you would have to create a new GCP project and a new App Engine.

I'm not very familiar with the Firebase products or the migration process from GCM to FCM, but if what you need is to switch from Cloud Datastore to [Cloud Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/), be aware that [this change will be done automatically](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/upgrade-to-firestore) in the future.

You can also [contact GCP support directly](https://cloud.google.com/support/) and request the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I'm not able to create a new Firestore database, which is the "new" Firebase database currently in beta. This because I already using the Cloud Datastore in my current app engine project and cheese two cannot coexist whiten the same app engine project. However I was able to create a "old" Firebase database (real time database).

I don't really need a new database or my existing one migrated, I only need messaging to work (FCM) and using the Admin SDK the only way to initialise the library I need a database.